# App installation fails due to missing Open Mobile API shared library

Tags: android, smartcard, sim-card, open-mobile-api, secure-element

I'm developing an app that uses Open Mobile API. I added this line to my manifest:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.simalliance.openmobileapi" android:required="true"/>
```

When I remove this line of code, it installs ok. But the app is not working properly. But if I add that line, I get the error

> install_failed_missing_shared_library

Is this because the API is not compatible with my device? I'm using a Famoco device.

Any workarounds on this one?

Comment: use android:required="false"

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar - I need the library. But basing from Michael's response, seems that I need to change my device in order for me to read the card/sem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error indicates that the Open Mobile API is not available on your device. If the Open Mobile API is not required for your application to work (e.g. if your app also does other things that do not rely on accessing a secure element through OMAPI), you might want to consider setting the attribute `android:required` to false:

```
<uses-library android:name="org.simalliance.openmobileapi" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: I see.. Is there any workaround on this? I'm trying to access a secure element. For starters, getting the ATR of the SEM.

Comment: @Jujumancer I'm not sure I understand what you mean with "workaround". Either your device supports OMAPI or not. If it does not, does it even have an accessible SE?

Comment: What I mean by "workaround" is, is there any other way for me to read data from secured element.  What do you mean by SE?

Comment: @Jujumancer SE = secure element; What type of secure element? What Android version? What exact device model?

Comment: MT65XX Android Phone android version 19. SAM card

Comment: @Jujumancer MediaTek MT65xx seems to be a family of mobile device SoC and not a model number of a specifc Android device... Btw. did you insert the SAM card into a regular SIM slot?

Comment: Yes, I tried inserting it also into the regular SIM slot. Unfortunately, it gives me the install failed message. I already tried installing the program to a compatible device and it installed successfully.

Comment: @Jujumancer you can try to find some CyanogenMod ROM for your phone -- it might work.

Comment: @vlp - already found one. it was a vendor specific jar. thank you though.